# TinyMce 4 util.i18n.translate() usage

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I try since hours and using the (very less helpful API [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.util/tinymce.util.i18n/) :S) to get translation for my plugin working.

```
tinymce.translate('Cut'); // returns Ausschneiden for de
```

So far, so good.

```
tinymce.translate('myplugin.test'); // returns myplugin.test
```

I checked tinymce.i18n.data and can see through inspector that it contains the data I added with

```
tinymce.addI18n('de.myplugin', {
    "test": 'test label'
});
```

before.

This is probably something stupid but I can not figure it out.

**UPDATE**

I now add my own functionality to do it manually as I can not figure it out how to do it:

```
plugin_translate = function(val) {
  return (eval('tinymce.i18n.data.' + tinymce.settings.language + '.' + val) != undefined)
  ? eval('tinymce.i18n.data.' + tinymce.settings.language + '.' + val)
  : val;
}
```

And my plugin/langs/de.js looks like this

```
tinymce.addI18n('de', { 'plugin': { "title" : 'Titel' }});
```

This doesn't look right but at the moment it works until someone enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translations are registered using [`tinymce.addI18n(langCode, translationMap)`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#addi18n) or [`tinymce.util.I18n.add(langCode, translationMap)`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.util/tinymce.util.i18n/#add).

The first parameter is a language code like "en", "en_US" or "de". This should be the same value used for the [`language` init property](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/localization/#language). Note that you should not include the plugin prefix here.

The second parameter is a map of translation-key to translation pairs. The translations can take positional arguments like `{0}` and `{1}`. You should prefix your keys with your plugin name to avoid naming clashes. For example:

```
{
  "myplugin.test": "test label",
  "myplugin.greeting": "Hello {0}, you are welcome"
}
```

So combining all those parts together you might register English and German translations like:

```
tinymce.addI18n("en", {
    "myplugin.title": "My Plugin",
    "myplugin.greeting": "Hello {0}, you are welcome"
});
tinymce.addI18n("de", {
    "myplugin.title": "Mein Plugin",
    "myplugin.greeting": "Hallo {0}, du bist willkommen"
});
```

Then to use the translation call [`tinymce.translate(translationKey)`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#translate) which returns the translated string. For a string without arguments you can just pass the same key you used in the map. For example:

```
var title = tinymce.translate("myplugin.title");
```

If your translation has parameters you have to wrap the key up in an array. For example:

```
var name = getName(); // get the name from the user
var greeting = tinymce.translate(["myplugin.greeting", name]);
```

If for some reason you need to override the translation you can provide an object with a raw string. For example:

```
var name = getName(); // get the name from the user
var key = name === "James" ? {"raw": "Go away!"} : ["myplugin.greeting", name];
var greeting = tinymce.translate(key);
```

Comment: Hello James, thank you for your answer. I try this for a plugin I published on github.com, there I have the lang files like you described => https://github.com/YvesR/tinymce-imgmap/blob/master/imgmap/langs/de.js. But this does not work as tinymce.translate('myplugin.test') does not return the translated value. Any hint?

Comment: In the file you link you have nested the object
``` { 'imgmap': {
"title" : 'Image Map Editor',
...
}}
```
but from my reading of the source ( https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/7b10860a76a07db43ad0677bee4b2db64dbddef0/src/core/main/ts/api/util/I18n.ts#L62 ) I don't think TinyMCE supports that. You need to write something like:
```
{
"imgmap.title": 'Image Map Editor',
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, with your answer and comments I were able to fix it.